# I need to edit/overwrite a text file that holds a customers information using easygui and i need to select which customers information i am editing

Tags: python, easygui

This is my python code you will need easy gui to run it and the username is q and the password is 1 i need to select a customer and then overwrite there information and not change the id number that it already has the code is from a different program i have wrote and the create despatch notes is the edit function or the not edit function i guess

```
   #Kit order database
from easygui import *
import csv
from easygui import EgStore
from datetime import *

import os
username = ""
password = ""
failed = 0

#continue/cancel box to request authentication to start the program
proceedLogon = ccbox("Authentication required to use this program","Security")

#if cancel is selected on the continue/cancel box to start the program
if proceedLogon == 0:
    exit()

#while username or password are wrong and some of the 3 treis remain"
while (username != "q" or password != "1") and failed < 3:
    #set a list for field names to enter
    fieldNames = ["Username","Password"]
    #create a list of values input in multi password box
    fieldValues = multpasswordbox("Logon","System Access",fieldNames)

    #handle user using cancel button on multpasswordbox, setting username to an
    #empty string which will give a failed atte,pt
    if fieldValues == None:
        proceedLogon = ccbox("Are you sure you want to exit?","Logon")

        # if continue is selected on the continue/cancel box exit the program
        if proceedLogon == 1:
            exit()
    else:
        #assign username and password to values input by user
        username = fieldValues[0]
        password = fieldValues[1]

    #add one to the failed count if the username or password is wrong
    if (username != "q" or password != "1"):
        failed = failed+1

    #if fail count exhausted
    if failed == 3:
        #message box to state login has failed
        msgbox("Login failed")
        #exit the program
        exit()
    elif(username !="q" or password !="1") and failed < 3:
        #build a string for message box output to show number of tries remaining
        failedMessage = (str(3-failed)+" tries remaining")
        msgbox(failedMessage, "Failed Logon")

#if username and password are corret start the program
msgbox("Login successful")

#function to add a record to a givern record
def setUpFolders():
    #if the program does not see a Invoices folder it creates one
    if not os.path.exists("invoices"):
        os.makedirs("invoices")
    #if the program does not see a despatch notes folder it creates one
    if not os.path.exists("despatch notes"):
        os.makedirs("despatch notes")
    #if the program does not see a paid invoices folder it creates one
    if not os.path.exists("paid invoices"):
        os.makedirs("paid invoices")
        
def addRecord(values, filename):

    #set highest file number to 01
    highestFileID = 0

    #try opening file for reading, else use w+ to create file
    #and reading records from file to get the highest ID number from first record
    
    try:
        file = open(filename, "r+")

        #for each line in the file
        for line in file:
            #create a blank list for each line of the file to be read into
            records = []

            #at each pipe character split the string 
            for field in line.split("|"):
                #add each entry in turn to a new position in the list
                records.append(field)

            #if the number in the first postition in the
            #list is higher than the current highestfileID
            if int(records[0]) > highestFileID:
                #update the highestFileID to that higher
                #number which is in the 1st positio of the list
                highestFileID = int(records[0])

        file.close()

    #if file isn't there then create the file
    except EnvironmentError as exception:
        #create file for later appending
        file = open(filename,"w+")

    #create primary key for record
    key = str(highestFileID + 1)
    #create string for record joining the key to the details sent to this function(member/kit item/order)
    record = "|".join([key] + values)

    #write string to appropriate record file
    file = open(filename,"a")
    file.write(record + "\n")
    file.close()

    #returns next runner,event or entry ID
    return highestFileID + 1 

            
def enterClubMember():

    #set fields for member information input dialogue box
    msg = "Enter the new information"
    title = "Add a new member"
    fieldNames = ["Name","Street Address","Town/City","Postcode"]

    #setting user details as a blank list
    fieldValues = []

    #set number of complete entries member details to 0
    numberOfEntries = 0
    #while there are less than 4 complete entries
    while numberOfEntries < 4:
        #input field values(new member details) in a multenter box
        fieldValues = multenterbox(msg,title,fieldNames)

        #cancel button option for member details entry to return to the menu
        if fieldValues == None:
            mainMenu()

        #check each entry is the input list to see if it is not blank
        #adding one to the complete entry count as appropriate
        for entry in fieldValues:
                if entry != "":
                    numberOfEntries += 1

        #show error message if any of the lines was found to be blank 
        if numberOfEntries < 4:
            msgbox("All fields must be filled in")
            #reset counter for complete entries ready for data re-entry
            numberOfEntries = 0
            
    
    #format member details for neat case
    fieldValues[0] = fieldValues[0].title()
    fieldValues[1] = fieldValues[1].title()
    fieldValues[2] = fieldValues[2].title()
    fieldValues[3] = fieldValues[3].upper()

    #return the list of entered member details to file by
    #calling the addRecord function sending parametres of
    #the member details list and the file name to save to
    addRecord(fieldValues,"Bank company customers.txt")



    
def recordList(fileName):

    #set record list empty
    records = []
    #attempt to open the requested filename
    try:
        file = open(fileName, "r+")

        #process each line of the file
        for line in file:
            #create 2d list of contects from each line if the records file
            records.append(line.split("|"))

        file.close()
    #if the file cannot be opened or loooped through
    except EnvironmentError as exception:
        msgbox("Could not open/read from the file")
        #would return nothing
        return None

    #return records to the calling function
    return records


#creating a function and setting it to createDespatchNote()
def createDespatchNote():
    msg = "Enter the new information"
    title = "Add a new member"
    fieldNames = ["Name","Street Address","Town/City","Postcode"]

    #calling a different function to find the text file 
    orderList = recordList("Bank company customers.txt")
    updatedlist=[]
    temporarylist=[]
    
    with open("Bank company customers.txt",newline="") as f:
      reader=list(csv.reader(f))#convert iterable to a list to make it easier 
      ynbox("CHANGE PASSWORD?!")
      username=enterbox("Enter the name for the required customer:")
      temporarylist=reader #store a copy of the data
      
      for row in reader: #for every row in the file
          for field in row:
                if field==username: #if a field is == to the required username
                    updatedlist.append(row) #add each row, line by line, into a list called 'udpatedlist'
                    newpassword=multenterbox(msg,title,fieldNames)
                    updatedlist[1][2] = newpassword #set the field for password to the new password
               
      
      updatepassword(updatedlist,temporarylist)
        
def updatepassword(updatedlist,temporarylist):
    for index, row in enumerate(temporarylist):
        for field in row:
            if field==updatedlist[1]:
                temporarylist[index]=updatedlist #replace old record with updated records

    
    with open("Bank company customers.txt","w",newline="") as f:
        Writer=csv.writer(f)
        Writer.writerows(temporarylist)
        print("File has been updated")


    
    

    

    
def markInvoiceAsPaid():

    #calling a different function to find the text file
    orderList = recordList("Bank Members.txt")
    #if their isnt a file ouput error
    if orderList == None:
        msgbox("Error reading order file")
        return

    #setting choicelist to an empty list
    choiceList = []

    #for every order in the text file run the following code
    for order in orderList:
        #setting choice to a blank string
        choice = ""
        #for every position in the order
        for field in order:

            #after each field add a double space
            choice += "{}|".format(field)
        #after the choice list add the users choice to the end of the list 
        choiceList.append(choice)

    #creating a title and message to go in a choice box
    title = "Mark order as paid"
    msg = "Select order to mark as paid"
    #creating a choice box to mark the order as paid 
    orderChoice = choicebox(msg,title,choiceList)

    #if their is no orders in the choice return to the main menu
    if orderChoice == None:
        mainMenu()

    #setting markAsPaidID as order choice split with double space at position 0 with a strip
    markAsPaidID = orderChoice.split("  ")[0].strip()

    #setting invoiceFile as the invoices text file
    invoiceFile = "invoices/order {} - confirmation.txt".format(markAsPaidID)

    #if their is not an invoice file follow the following code
    if os.path.isfile(invoiceFile):
        #rename a text file called paid invoices and mark it as paid
        os.rename(invoiceFile,"paid invoices/Order {} - paid.txt".format(markAsPaidID))
        #creating a message to be used in a text box
        msg = "Order " + markAsPaidID + " has been marked as paid"
        #telling the user that the order has been marked as paid
        msgbox(msg,"Confirmation")
        return
    #if the order does not successfully get marked as paid output an error
    else:
        msg = "failed to mark invoice as paid, because the original invoice could not be found"
        msgbox(msg,"Failed operation")

#creating a function for unpaid invoices
def checkForUnpaidInvoices():

    #setting unpaid invoices as an empty list
    unpaidInvoices = []

    #for every file in invoices 
    for filename in os.listdir("invoices"):

        #try the following code
        try:
            #checking the date on the text file name 
            modifiedTime = os.path.getmtime("invoices/" + filename)
        #if their is no time in the file name then it will outpun an error
        except OSError:
            modifiedTime = 0
            msgbox("Unable to find files to check dates","Error")
            
        #setting modified date 
        modifiedDate = datetime.fromtimestamp(modifiedTime)

        #if modified date is more than 7 add it to the unpaid invoices file
        if modifiedDate + timedelta(days=7) < datetime.now():
            unpaidInvoices.append(filename)

    #if the unpaid invoices file is larger than 0 run the following code
    if len(unpaidInvoices) > 0:
        #output the unpaid invoices
        msgbox("\n".join(unpaidInvoices),"Unpaid invoices")
    #if their are no unpaid invoices outputing saying that their are no unpaid invoices
    else:
        msgbox("There are not unpaid receipts over 7 days old","Report")
    
def mainMenu():

    #initialise choice to an option that is not available
    choice = 5

    #while choice isnt the exit option
    while choice != 0:
        #set the button names as a list
        choices = ["Exit","New club member",
                   "New kit item","New kit order & receipt","Create despatch note",
                   "Mark invoice as paid","check for unpaid orders over 7 days old"]

        #input users gui choice
        choice = indexbox("Choose a menu option","Kit Orders Database",
                          choices)

        #if the choice to exit is selected then exit with a message
        if choice == 0:
            msgbox("Good bye!")
            exit()
        #else if choice is 1 call the enter club member function
        elif choice == 1:
            enterClubMember()
        #else if choice is 2 call the enter kit item function
        elif choice == 2:
            enterKitItem()
        #else if choice is 3 call the enter kit order function
        elif choice == 3:
            enterKitOrder()
        #else if choice is 4 call the create despatch note function
        elif choice == 4:
            createDespatchNote()
        #else if choice is 5 call the mark invoice as paid  function
        elif choice == 5:
            markInvoiceAsPaid()
        #else if choice is 6 call the check for unpaid invoices  function
        elif choice == 6:
            checkForUnpaidInvoices()

        #option for user using red cross exit button output invalid option
        elif choice == None:
            msgbox("Use the \"Exit\" option to leave the program","Invalid option")

#calling the main menu function
mainMenu()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).